# Can't resolve casbah as a sbt dependency

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I'm getting the following error upon compile:

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.mongodb#casbah_2.11;2.7.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

With this build.sbt file:

```
name := """play-scala"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)

libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.7.4-SNAPSHOT"

// For stable releases
resolvers += "Sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

// For SNAPSHOT releases
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
```

I'm using Typesafe Activator and have tried many combinations of Casbah versions (including releases, instead of snapshots) and resolvers. The [installation instructions from the "official" MongoDB Casbah tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/guide/installation.html) don't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go to the release and snapshot URLs and try to manually locate casbah, you'll see that the [snapshot url doesn't have anything for casbah](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/mongodb/) currently.

On the other hand, the release repo has 2.7.3 for Scala 2.11. [Check it out here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/casbah_2.11/2.7.3/).

Maybe try

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.7.3"
```

Comment: I'll fix up the docs - sorry I built them after bumping the version for future work.  Just as an FYI main releases are always announced on the mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-casbah-users Generally in Casbah snapshots are only released as and when the code diverges from the previous stable release.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with 2.7.4 and adding `pomOnly()`made it work. `libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.7.4" pomOnly()`

Answer (score 0):

use following dependancy in your build.sbt file :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "2.8.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

use these lib

```
  "org.mongodb" %% "casbah" % "3.1.1",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.5.2",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-mongo" % "3.5.2"
```